Horror movie that involves a trailer in the woods and a quarantine zone
Plot: I forget the title of the movie but it's a group of friends going out camping in a trailer and at night they hear sounds and one by one they go missing. Eventually it turns out they're in a quarantine zone and the military are everywhere exterminating the monsters and the surviving pair run through the woods and into some military buildings and they run into one military guy and they escape and continue on and then climb out and it turns out they're in the desert and a helicopter comes and takes them away.
Year: Saw it last year, probably released in the last 5 years.
Country: It's American.

Sounds like the found-footage horror film Evidence from 2012.

Ryan is making a documentary on his friend, Brett, about camping for the first time. However, once they begin camping, they discover that there is a mysterious figure that is hunting them.

It all pretty much fits: The group of friends go missing one by one, they find out they're in some quarantined military zone, come across a soldier, escape zombies and finally board a helicopter. Here's the trailer:



